# Stored Procedure Create Failing When using CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

Running SQL Server 2008. Each part of the stored procedure below runs fine. The stored procedure was originally just the insert statement which works. The CTE with select/delete runs fine on its own, too.

I'm adding the CTE with delete statement to the stored procedure to remove duplicates so I can run as much as I need during development without getting duplicates in subsequent processing.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE db.sproc_name(@data nvarchar(max))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @doc AS INT
    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @doc OUTPUT, @data

    INSERT INTO db.the_table
        SELECT * 
        FROM openxml(@doc, '/XPATH_STRING', 1) 
        WITH db.the_table

    ;WITH cte AS
    (
        SELECT
            *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATE, CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS rn
        FROM
            db.the_table
    )
    DELETE FROM cte 
    WHERE rn > 1
END
```

I'm getting this error when running the create statement:

> 15:51:16  [error codes...] Incorrect syntax near 'the_table'.
>   15:51:16  [error codes...]  Incorrect syntax near 'end'.
>   ... 2 statement(s) executed, 0 rows affected, exec/fetch time: 
>     0.005/0.000 sec  [0 successful, 2 errors]

Edited to remove quotes in identifier.

Comment: Is `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` on or off? Do you get the same issue with `create PROCEDURE [db].[sproc_name]`?

Comment: I didn't realize that was an option. It was off, but removing the quotes didn't resolve nor did turning it on.

Comment: No syntax issues on create here. http://rextester.com/OAQJ29099. What is this "2 statement(s) executed"?

Comment: is db.the_table supposed to be dbo.the-table or is your schema really db?

Comment: Also if you are on 2008 check the compatibility level of the database in case it's something even older.

Comment: DB name, Table name and xpath string would be too strong of a hint about proprietary activities so I changed.

Comment: Compatibility at 100 for all databases. Just saw the 2 statement(s) executed, not sure whats going on there.

Comment: What client tool are you using? (SMSS, SQLCMD, other). It is reporting two statements executed, but `create ...` is the only statement that would be executed. It looks like the stored procedure is being broken at the semi-colon and fed as two seperate batches to SQL Server. First syntax error is because the first batch is missing closing `end`. Second syntax error is the `end` without a `begin`.

Comment: OT: `FROM OPENXML` with the corresponding SPs to prepare and to remove a document is outdated and should not be used any more (rare exceptions exist). Rather use the appropriate [methods the XML data type provides](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx).

Comment: Following on from what @ShannonSeverance has said: Do you have ; (semi-colon) configured as batch separator in SSMS?

Comment: That was it! I'm using dbvisualizer pro 9.5.3. I can't believe this hasnt come up before but changing the delimiter to ;; from ; made it work. Please rewrite as answer so I can mark as correct.

Comment: Btw: you are missing the removal procedure